# Can an IIS application pool be restricted to 1 working process and 1 thread?

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, iis-6

I have to see if I can work around a known thread safety issue on third party component. The plan was to let an ASP.Net app to talk to the third party component via a WCF service, this was based on the assumption that I will be able to assign the WCF service to it's own application pool, restrict the pool to one working process and the working process to one thread. Requests to the service will have to wait for their turn, but that's OK because we expect them to require very little time and to be rare as well.
Problem is, I can't find anything that suggests how to achieve this part: "restrict the working process to one thread".
I have found a few useful pages, but no solution:

- On [IISforums](http://forums.iis.net/t/1177478.aspx?Influencing%20the%20number%20of%20threads%20per%20IIS%20worker%20processes), the discussion seem to suggest that I can achieve this in IIS 7+ but does not mention IIS6.
- On [MSDN Blogs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2007/07/21/asp-net-thread-usage-on-iis-7-0-and-6-0.aspx) and linked MSDN books chapter (can't put the link because I'm new here!) the discussion is mostly about what you can set via the machine.config file, which, if I'm understanding it correctly, is going to apply to all AppPools/Worker processes and is not what I'm trying to do, I would like to control what one single app can do, leaving the other applications untouched.

Questions:

- **Is it possible to achieve what I'm trying to do?** (assign the WCF service to it's own application pool, restrict the pool to one working process and the working process to one thread" via IIS 6 configurations)
- **If not, can this be achieved programmatically somehow?** For example, using locks or other threading-related tricks within my WCF service implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't make much sense to me.. A web server have to be multithreaded by definition, because it must handle different income messages at the same time, if there is only one thread once in use any new request will fail.

What about to wrap the component in a class with a SynchonizationAttribute, so only one thread can access the component? Even if this will make your solution less scalable, at least it may work

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.contexts.synchronizationattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Doesn't make much sense to me either, but hey, it's not an ideal world. Why SynchonizationAttribute (with a static member, I'd guess) and not a lock? I've never used locks so far and never heard about SynchonizationAttribute before your reply...

Comment: @SergioG When the world is not ideal is because it lacks of good architectural design ;-) That said, SynchonizationAttribute works like a lock on the type.
http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx